# Delete sms android after receiving With no delay

Tags: android, sms

I have some code to delete Android SMS messages programatically but when I try to delete it in onReceive then no SMS is deleted.

Sample code to delete sms

```
try {
    // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS from inbox");
    Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
        uriSms, new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "address", "person",
        "date", "body" }, null, null, null);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            long id = c.getLong(0);
            long threadId = c.getLong(1);
            String address = c.getString(2);
            String body = c.getString(5);

            if (message.equals(body) && address.equals(number)) {
                // mLogger.logInfo("Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // mLogger.logError("Could not delete SMS from inbox: " +
    // e.getMessage());
}
```

When I paste this in `onReceived` then the new SMS is not deleted.

Comment: is there any solution??

Comment: @user2229896 accept the answer so it would be removed from unanswered list on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add permissions to your manifest file and increase **priority** of your **SMS Receiver** class

```
<receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" > 
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

This is because it will call the SMSReceiver before any OS level operations like(Saving SMS, notification, SMS Sound And so on.).

Then in SMSReceiver  **onReceive()** you need to add **abortBroadcast()** to abort any further Broadcasts

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  abortBroadcast();
}
```

that's all

cheers

Ayush Shah

Answer (score 0):

You must delete `sms` with `Smsid`

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + smsid), null, null);
```